# By tensoring with $\Bbb Q$ a short exact sequence, why does $A/B$ have rank $0$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, tensor-products, abelian-groups, exact-sequence

Let $A, B$ be free abelian groups of rank $n$. That is, $A$ and $B$ are both isomorphic to $\Bbb Z^n.$

Now, $0\to B\to A\to A/B\to 0$ is short exact sequence.

By tensoring with $\Bbb Q$, we get 
$$0\to B\otimes \Bbb Q\to A\otimes \Bbb Q \to A/B\otimes \Bbb Q\to 0.$$

Thus, $A/B$ has rank $0$.

But why?

I cannot follow logic.

I guess $A\otimes \Bbb Q\to A/B\otimes \Bbb Q$ is the zero mapping, but I cannot prove this claim.

And, in the proof above, the properties of short exact sequence seem to be not used. What is the merit of using short exact sequence in this situation?

Thank you very much for your kind help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $A, B$ are free abelian groups of rank $n$, both $B\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}}\mathbb{Q}$ and $A\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}}\mathbb{Q}$ are $n$-dimensional vector spaces over $\mathbb{Q}$. Next you accepted the fact that the sequence

$$0\rightarrow B\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}}\mathbb{Q} \rightarrow A\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}}\mathbb{Q}\rightarrow A/B\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}}\mathbb{Q} \rightarrow 0$$

is exact, which is nontrivial. Tensor product $(-)\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}}C$ does not in general preserve left exactness (it always preserves right exactness). It does iff you are tensoring with torsion-free abelian group $C$ and $\mathbb{Q}$ is indeed torsion-free. Since you accepted this fact, note that part of your exact sequence is a monomorphism $B\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}}\mathbb{Q} \rightarrow A\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}}\mathbb{Q}$ between two $\mathbb{Q}$-vector spaces of the same dimension. This implies that this monomorphism is an isomorphism and hence $A/B\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}}\mathbb{Q} = 0$.

Machinery of short exact sequences is just a convenient language to speak about this particular subject matter. Link you provided contains arguments formulated in other but equivalent languages (they are translatable).

Comment: Thank you for your great elaborated answer !

Comment: You are welcome! I am very glad that you find it useful.

Comment: I think , as you kindly tought me, flatness of Q as Z module and the fact 'The rank of an abelian group A coincides with the dimension of the Q-vector space A ⊗z Q' is the important thing. Am I right ?

Comment: Yes. These are two premises of the argument. From them everything else follows.

Comment: I didn't know the later fact 'The rank of an abelian group A coincides with the dimension of the Q-vector space A ⊗z Q' . Is the proof easy? I could not find the proof in internet.

Comment: If you have any references about this fact, I would be grateful if you could tell me。

Comment: Let $A$ be a free abelian group of rank $n$. Then $A \cong \mathbb{Z}^{\oplus n}$ i.e. $A$ is a direct sum of $n$-copies of $\mathbb{Z}$. Since tensor product preserves direct sums, you can deduce that $A\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}}\mathbb{Q} \cong \mathbb{Q}^{\oplus n}$.

Comment: excellent..Thank you so much.